# How to automate database table backup without cron

Tags: php, mysql, database-backups

So I have a web application, where each month, a MYSQL database table should be backed up for historical purposes. The table name would be it's name, followed by the current year, and the month it should represent, like `table_201811` or `table_201901`, etc., you get the idea.

I don't have SSH access, so no classic cron job possibility.

I thought, one way, is that, since PHP doesn't running all the time, at each page load, I would:

- get the latest table name
- get the year and month from that
- compare it to current year and month
- check if current year and month table exist
- create if not, and copying all the data

Now, there is nothing wrong with that, I think, however, everybody can see that it is not an optimal solution, as there are at least 2 MYSQL requests involved.

How could I improve on this process? Is there another, better approach to that?

**Edit:**
One possible way to accomplish that, albeit not the most elegant one:

- save the next backup date in a file on the server
- on every page load, compare that date with current date
- if equal or bigger, check if table already has been created
- create if not, and copy all the data
- set the next date in the file on the server

Any thoughts on that?

**Edit2**

So in the end I went with the above concept, except I have used the database to store the next backup date, since, as I have learned, **reading from/writing** to, a file, via PHP, is **slower** then accessing the database. One would argue with this, as the database files are also plain files physically on the hard disk, but anyway. This is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Inferring from the point of having no SSH access, someone else is doing the hosting for you? Ask them to do a backup script like you want it, and put it into crontab.

They hopefully already have some kind of backup system running, if not, consider to switch to somewhere else as soon as possible.

Also, (putting my ops hat on for now) they most certainly are interested if you're going to accumulate monthly full-copies of your data into the database. For this reason too, it'd be wise to consult them first.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. It's a shared host, I am not in contact with the hosting company. Of course, what you are saying does make sense, and certainly would be the best option, however I'm afraid I have to stick both to PHP, and with the current company. By the way, the data I need backup from is not big, like a few dozens of rows now, and with time, at most, a few hundred lines.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with your assessment that you are "not in contact with the hosting company", when the fact is you are writing code to be run on their servers. If their immediate contact is your client or equivalent, you should pester your client for that contact. Do you have a way to export your data from them? That is another thing you really should look into, not only for this.

Comment: I have SFTP connection to the server, have cPanel, and phpMyAdmin. So an export, both via cPanel and PMA is possible, yes. You're correct, saying that the "immediate contact is the client or equivalent". And yes, leaving aside the programming side of the problem, I agree with you, should do that. Still, I am interested from a programming point of view, as I am planning to run such application on a local server, too, where no third party is involved, and would like to achieve the same, without cron (for various reasons which doesn't matter now).

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to write a backup script which is callable via a URL and use .htaccess Basic Auth protection for that URL, so others cannot call it.

Then use a service like cron-job.org which calls this URL once a day.

Comment: Interesting approach, have not thought about involving a URL, kinda like an API.. The only downside is that those third party services could, or could not, be reliable, in the long term. But the backup script via URL is definitely a good idea. Thank you.